# SUMIFs in Google sheets with 2 filters on same criteria range

Tags: excel, google-sheets, sumifs

I have looked at various answers but all use filters on different columns. I need an OR type filter like this:

`=SUMIFs(B2:B22,C2:C22,"Incurred",C2:C22,"Expected")`

Where C2:C22 specifies if the cell in B is an incurred or expected or deferred expense.

How do I do this? Note the filters are on the same set of cells in column C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the data in `A6:C6`:

```
1   A   C
2   B   D
3   A   D
4   B   C
5   A   D
6   B   D
```

To sum the values if column B is `A` or column C is `D` you can use:

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA((IF(((B1:B6="A")+(C1:C6="D"))>0,A1:A6))))
```

This uses the fact that `True` equals `1` and `False` equals `0` once you want to use them in equation.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this...

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((C2:C22="Incurred")+(C2:C22="Expected")+(C2:C22="Deferred"))*B2:B22)
```